# Updating a partial view or redirecting to another view depending on the model state

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, response.redirect

I have a modal popup window containing a form that is opened after I click on a button. I would like to be redirected to the homepage if the model state is valid, otherwise I would like the content of the form to be updated with the errors if it's not valid.

I currently have the code below, I can't seem to find something better. The problem is that if the model is correct, the homepage is loaded inside the modal popup window because of the UpdateTargetId specified in the Ajax.BeginForm function.

This represents the content I have in the body of my modal popup window :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateTask", "Accueil", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "partialCreateTask", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
...
}
```

Here is the function called in the controller :

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> CreateTask([Bind(Include = "Titre,Description,Echeance")] T_Tache t_tache)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var db = new My_DBEntities();

            t_tache.IdStatutTache = DataAccess_SELECT.GetIdOfTaskName(new Socfim_Plateforme_DBEntities(), "En cours");
            t_tache.UserCreation = DataAccess_STORE.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name).IdUser;
            t_tache.DateCreation = DateTime.Now;
            t_tache.AffecteA = DataAccess_STORE.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name).IdUser;

            db.T_Tache.Add(t_tache);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return PartialView("_PartialCreateTask", t_tache);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateTask([Bind(Include = "Titre,Description,Echeance")] T_Tache t_tache)
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        var db = new My_DBEntities();

                        t_tache.IdStatutTache = DataAccess_SELECT.GetIdOfTaskName(new Socfim_Plateforme_DBEntities(), "En cours");
                        t_tache.UserCreation = DataAccess_STORE.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name).IdUser;
                        t_tache.DateCreation = DateTime.Now;
                        t_tache.AffecteA = DataAccess_STORE.CurrentUser(User.Identity.Name).IdUser;

                        db.T_Tache.Add(t_tache);
                        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

                        return JavaScript("window.location = '/ControllerName/Index'");
                    }

                    return PartialView("_PartialCreateTask", t_tache);
                    
                }
```